# Tkinter: "NameError: name 'event' is not defined error" when passing argument in button command

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to pass the event argument in my button command function to create a toplevel, but I'm getting this error:
`NameError: name 'event' is not defined`

This is my code

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
                                                                                           
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack(fill='x')

        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='M', font='Verdana 13 bold', command= lambda: self.toplevel(event))
        self.button.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=10, pady=10)


    def toplevel(self, event):
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel()
        self.toplevel.overrideredirect(True)
        self.toplevel.geometry(f"100x130+{event.x}+{event.y}")      

        button = tk.Button(self.toplevel, text="Quit")
        button.pack(padx=5, pady=5, anchor='w')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()    
    root.title('Title')
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error obviously tells you what you are doing wrong.  What is `event` in `self.toplevel(event)` and where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Button press is not considered an event. An event is binding a function to a mouse, or keyboard action. In this example I get the cursor position upon left click, relative to the top left corner of the screen. The event is bound to the root widget.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
                                                                                           
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack(fill='x')

        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='M', font='Verdana 13 bold', command= lambda: self.toplevel(x, y))
        self.button.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=10, pady=10)


    def toplevel(self, x, y):
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel()
        self.toplevel.overrideredirect(True)
        self.toplevel.geometry(f"100x130+{x}+{y}")      

        button = tk.Button(self.toplevel, text="Quit")
        button.pack(padx=5, pady=5, anchor='w')


def get_event(event):
    global x, y
    x = event.x_root
    y = event.y_root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()    
    root.title('Title')
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.bind('<Button-1>', get_event)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your terminology is a bit strange. A button press _is_ an event, it's just that the `command` option of a button is not designed to pass an event object to the actual command.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='M', font='Verdana 13 bold', command= lambda: self.toplevel(event))
        

def toplevel(self, event):
```

to:

```
self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='M', font='Verdana 13 bold', command= lambda: self.toplevel())
     


def toplevel(self, event=None):
```

When you run the script. You will see a small window on top left